# Wrong ID proof selected for UK train ticket

Tags: trains, uk, tickets, paperwork

I have a problem. I recently booked a ticket to London through East Coast trains. I selected the print@home option and they asked for a ID proof. Being an international traveller I naturally gave my passport number. Unfortunately I forgot to change the options and the ticket recorded the "preferred ID proof" as a driving licence with the last 4 digits of my passport.
Now I am really worried since tickets on this route are quite expensive, and that the ticket checker should not create any issues while travelling.

Could someone suggest what to do? I tried to email the train company from their website, but so far no one has responded!

Comment: Did you try ringing them? They tend to have a few days delay on replying to emails

Comment: I would imagine you'll be fine, the ticket inspectors are fairly sensible and I doubt they'd even ask for ID when they check the ticket. Where are you starting from? In general I normally book the tickets for collection in the station (major stations have automated machines so there's rarely any queue).

Comment: Am travelling from York to London ! I don't have the option of automatic collection since my credit card is not from the UK and is of the older mag-strip only type (the station machines need ones with a chip)

Comment: Short of asking the company there's no way of confirming this. However, I don't think it should be a problem. Just explain at the ticket counter when you collect your ticket what happened. ID is not checked on trains.

Comment: UK rail ticket machines normally need a chip to buy a ticket, but are you sure they need one when just collecting one bought online?

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee - Oh yes they do ! though they do forget sometimes, but most of the time i used an E-ticket, they had a look at my documents.

Comment: @Gagravarr - well honestly i think mag strip should work, but most seem to mention chip cards so wanted to be safe than sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so I made a lengthy international call and got it sorted out ! 
Basically they said its no problem and just carry both ID and tell the guard - At the end passports are considered a more reliable proof of identification !

Plus I even received a reply from the company ! - here's the reply -

```
Thank you for your email dated 29/11/2013, regarding your tickets.

You will be required to take both forms of identification with you when
you travel and advise the train guard of what has happened when asked,
this will enable you to travel on your tickets.

Thank you for taking the time to contact East Coast Web Support, If you
have any further questions please do not hesitate to contact us on 08457
225 111.

Your sincerely


Web Customer support
East Coast Mainline
PO Box 6136
Wolverhampton
WV1 9RL
Tel: 0845 722 5111
Email: webcustomersupport@eastcoast.co.uk
www.eastcoast.co.uk
```

Comment: I imagine you've dealt with this now - but in case any future readers need this, I'd suggest printing the email as well. Then you have something in writing that says that the train operator told you to do this, in case you end up with a train guard who has a different opinion.

Comment: I actually did consider it, but I had my tablet with me and the email obviously on it. though the ticket checker didn't even ask for ID proof !

Comment: Well that works too!

Comment: East Coast trains no longer require you to specify which ID proof you will be using when you purchase the ticket. You can use any of card, driving licence or passport if the conductor asks for ID.